# Yii2 triggering a model/record update from afterSave

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

After saving a new model / active record in Yii2, I'm scheduling a job on the filesystem. I do this in afterSave and I would like to update the record with the job id of the scheduler I get back.

But when I call $this->update() in the model after setting the correct property to the job id, no update is happening. Using update() in an afterSave() is probably a bad idea, but what would then be the right way to tackle this?

Comment: It would be infinite loop. Do this logic in beforeSave().

Comment: That makes sense, but I need the id of the saved record to pass to the scheduler. So BeforeSave() is not an option.

Comment: You could simply override `update`, or use/override `save`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 options there:

1. Create additional internal field in the model, something like `private $task_sended = false;` In afterUpdate set task_sended = true and check It

   if (!$this->task_sended){
       //send task to scheduler
       $this->task_sended = true;
   }
2. Use DAO command to update model

   \Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update(self::tableName(), $update, ['id'=>$this->id])->execute();

Comment: @soju sorry, updated for Yii 2, i thought it's Yii 1

Comment: @Alex thanks, option 2 works fine. However, the syntax is slightly different, could you update your answer to \Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update(self::tableName(), $update, ['id'=>$this->id])->execute(); The $update is an array with key=>value pairs of the columns to update.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `updateAttributes($attributes)`

> This method is a shortcut to `update()` when data validation is not
>   needed and only a small set attributes need to be updated.
>
> You may specify the attributes to be updated as name list or
>   name-value pairs. If the latter, the corresponding attribute values
>   will be modified accordingly. The method will then save the specified
>   attributes into database.
>
> Note that this method will **not** perform data validation and will **not**
>   trigger events.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#updateAttributes()-detail